# Firestore and mysql connection issue

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-firestore

I have mobile app using Firestore and I created Laravel project. By this project I store data info Firestore data also. Now I am try to export data to MySQL db. When Firestore updated I want to export data to MySQL. Can anyone suggest me what can I do for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it manually.

Firestore is a NoSQL database whereas MySQL is an SQL database (duh). The thing about NoSQL databases is the lack of structure but MySQL **must** have an structure, so you will have to design it, export the data from Firestore, transform it into a valid SQL import file and import it.

Now the thing is that this operation between databases of different type shouldn't be done as they are used differently and for different reasons. Unless the choice of database type was wrong right from the beginning.

I recommend you to reconsider if this is the right step to take as it won't be an easy task.